# Deployment Fails of Xmrain forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamrian forms application here and I am having real issues getting deployed to my device, it works fine in the simulator. Used Shared Runtime is Unticked and the Use fast deployment is also unticked.

So I am at a loss when on my phone I push it out using the app distribution centre I am getting the following. And Yes I do have a singing certif

[image]

> App Not Installed
>
> The package appears to be corrupt

I am using Visual Studio 2019 16.1.1

[image]
[image]

As you see I have set this to be unticked as suggested by other SO posts. I have the package rebuilt and sent to the app centre for distribution get the email click on the download and the phone is set to unknown sources and still does not install.

Comment: Use Android Device Monitor, and go to the logcat, when you are trying to install, check what specific error is printed in the console.

Comment: Im installing throught app center microsoft

Comment: What option you have on android install location?

Comment: what andriod install location that doesnt make since

Comment: I am trying to deploy the xamrain forms app without it being teathered to the phone via usb it works fine on the phone but when try to use the apk locally by copying and or deploying using app centre it doesnt work

Comment: you did not even state where adriod location was or anything to be so sartcastic

Comment: Delete obj and bin folders from android and pcl projects then clean and rebuild. And try to create new certificate and sign it and check.